# Cannot add a parameter in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I cannot add a parameter in the Openpopup() function, when ever i try,i have an error. Need your assistance.
Thanks in advance.

```
   return "<a  onclick='return Openpopup()' class='btn btn-info btn-lg clickBtn'  data-val='" + data + "'>" + "View Detials" + "</a>";
```

Comment: What parameter????

Comment: show us `openpopup()` too

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Can you show us the code of the `Openpopup()` function ?

Comment: With such limited codes, we cannot suggest anything!

Comment: What is the `Openpopup()` function? What is the argument you are trying to add? What is the error you're receiving when you do? We need more information before we can start helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data to function like this: below is small example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var str = "This is testing string";
$("#testing").append("<a  onclick='return Openpopup(\""+str+"\")' class='btn btn-info btn-lg clickBtn'  data-val='1'> View String </a>")
});


function Openpopup(str) {
   alert(str);
}
```

// html

```
<div id="testing"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.Works perfect using your approach

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
onclick="return Openpopup(\''yourParameter'\')"
```

Generally, I would advise to use a JS or Jquery function here though, because this type of formatting quickly gets confusing and is hard to maintain.